# Mac OSX 10.3 Log fills up

Tags: mac-osx, logging

I'm using an old 99 blue and white G3 tower with OSX 10.3.9 on it and using Reason. After about 10 or more hours of leaving the program open, the log file fills up and on my relatively small partition, renders the program unable to save changes or do much of anything.
I routinely delete the old log files when the computer is on for long periods of time but is there a shell script that can automate this process?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want logrotate, which is the standard unix-y way to do this. If it's not included on your install, you can [get logrotate from DarwinPorts](http://logrotate.darwinports.com/).